# igraph get.shortest.path on Disconnected Graphs

Tags: r, igraph

I am working with a sparse undirected graph as a result of which there are many nodes which are isolated and many groups of nodes which are disconnected from other nodes. `shortest.paths` works fine but I'm unable to get `get.shortest.path` to return the answer between vertices that I know are connected -

```
$vpath
$vpath[[1]]
+ 0/3054 vertices, named:


$epath
NULL

$predecessors
NULL

$inbound_edges
NULL
```

And also get this warning -

```
Warning message:
In .Call("R_igraph_get_shortest_paths", graph, as.igraph.vs(graph,  :
  At structural_properties.c:740 :Couldn't reach some vertices
```

I assume I'm missing something obvious. If anybody can tell, it would be great. If not, I will try and make some mock data and upload it

Comment: Please include a reproducible example. Maybe your directed graph is connected, but not strongly connected.

Comment: It is not directed and it is disconnected. My graph theory is a little rusty but Djikstra should be able to handle disconnected graphs, right? If so, I'll try and make an example.